# Unexpected behaviour of fread() reading from binary file

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, fread

This program basically creates a list of flights with all their infos (read by the fread() function from a ListaVoli.bin). 
The list is made up mainly by nodes and each node contains a flight.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILE_NAME "/Users/Matt/Downloads/ListaVoli.bin"

struct flight {
    int flightCode;
    char destination[3];
    int scheduledDepHour;
    int scheduledDepMinute;
    int realDepHour;
    int realDepMinute;
    int passengers;
};

struct node {
    struct flight volo;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *addToList(struct node *list, struct flight voloIn) {
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newNode -> volo = voloIn;
    newNode -> next = list;
    return newNode;
}

void printList(struct node *list) {
    for (; list != NULL; list = list -> next) {
        printf("Code:%d\nDestination:%s\nDeparture:%d-%d\nReal:%d-%d\nPassengers:%d\n\n\n",
        list -> volo.flightCode,
        list -> volo.destination,
        list -> volo.scheduledDepHour,
        list -> volo.scheduledDepMinute,
        list -> volo.realDepHour,
        list -> volo.realDepMinute,
        list -> volo.passengers
        );
    }
}

void decolla(struct node *list, int flightCode, int realDepHour, int realDepMinute) {
    for (; list != NULL; list = list -> next) {
        if (flightCode == (list -> volo.flightCode)) { /*
            printf("Inserisci ora di partenza per il volo %d: ", flightCode);
            scanf("%d", &(list -> volo.realDepHour));
            printf("Inserisci minuto di partenza: ");
            scanf("%d", &(list -> volo.realDepMinute)); */
            list -> volo.realDepHour = realDepHour;
            list -> volo.realDepMinute = realDepMinute;
        }
    }
}

void delay(struct node *list) {
    for (; list != NULL; list = list -> next) {
        if ((list -> volo.realDepHour) - (list -> volo.scheduledDepHour) == 0) {
            if ((list -> volo.realDepMinute) - (list -> volo.scheduledDepMinute) > 5 && (list -> volo.realDepMinute) - (list -> volo.scheduledDepMinute) < 30) {
            printf("Il volo %d ha più di 5 minuti di ritardo\n", list -> volo.flightCode);
            continue;
            }
            if ((list -> volo.realDepMinute) - (list -> volo.scheduledDepMinute) > 30) {
                printf("Il volo %d ha più di 30 minuti di ritardo\n", list -> volo.flightCode);
                continue;
            }
        } else
            printf("Il volo %d ha più di 30 minuti di ritardo\n", list -> volo.flightCode);
    }
}

void passengersCount(struct node *list) {
    for (; list != NULL; list = list -> next) {
        if (list -> volo.passengers > 200) {
            printf("Il volo %d ha più di 200 passeggeri\n", list -> volo.flightCode);
            continue;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    struct node *first = NULL;
    struct flight volo;

    /* Apro il file e controllo che sia stato aperto correttamente */
    if ((fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        fread(&volo, sizeof(int), 7, fp);
        first = addToList(first, volo);
    }

    decolla(first, 3497, 11, 30);
    decolla(first, 2193, 11, 53);
    decolla(first, 4284, 11, 07);
    decolla(first, 5536, 12, 26);
    printList(first);
    delay(first);
    passengersCount(first);

    /* Controllo che il file sia chiuso correttamente */
    if (fclose(fp) == EOF) {
        printf("File not closed properly!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles correctly so don't worry about the entire code, focus on the main() functions and the two structs.
I have two questions regarding the fread() function in the main() function:

1. Why, if I put sizeof(int) as the second parameter, the flight.destination value is assigned correctly? Shouldn't a char[3] variable be larger than sizeof(int)?
2. Why, if I put sizeof(struct flight) as second parameter (which would be the best choice), I get segmentation fault:11?

Comment: If the rest of the code does not matter, you should not have posted it. Thats the idea of the the first part in [mcve].

Comment: You need the code to have a better understanding of the program. I have just said that the question is not about the entire program, but just the fread() function in the main() function.

Comment: That's ok, but reading from a binary file is complex and a single bit can create big issues. As you said, int is 4 bytes, char[3] is 3 bytes, then the fread() should have read more bytes than it should right? Then why do I get the correct output (a string of 3 char)?

Comment: There is no need to "understand the program". You have to tell what your **specific** problem is and provide the **necessary** code to reproduce. SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of three characters is three bytes. An `int` is usually (at least on modern 32 and 64 bit platforms) 4 bytes. It works to read `sizeof(int)` because the compiler adds *padding*.

But the "correct" (or at least usual) way to read the structure would be to read the whole structure as one single unit, i.e. using `sizeof(volo)` in your case:

```
fread(&volo, sizeof(volo), 1, fp);
```

If you get other errors because of it, you are doing something *else* wrong.

Comment: Actually the better (and corrcet) way would be to properly (de) serialise it element-wise.

Comment: And why you wrote 1 as third parameter instead of 7 as I did? Is mine solution incorrect?

Comment: Seems like it was that 7 that caused the segmentation fault:11 error

Comment: @matt95 The second argument is the *size* of each element to read, and the third argument is the *number* of elements to read.

Comment: That's right, indeed I put 7 because the struct is made up of 7 ints, isn't that correct?
But the error was when I put sizeof(struct flight) and 7 is incorrect, because it would read 7 sizeof(struct flight)! Now I understand the problem.

Comment: @matt95 Yes, the code you show will read seven `int` elements.